# JBoss http thread keep reading in SPECjEnterprise benchmark

Tags: http, web, threadpool, jboss7.x

I can run the benchmark with 50% util of an 8 core machine.
I must configure the http thread pool to 9000 to achieve this.
It's not reasonable to use thousands of threads in 8 core machine.
Most of the threads are waiting for reading http inputs.
There are around 6000 client threads driving the benchmark.
But I don't think it need to keep one thread for one connection.
Here is my jboss configuration: